# Could someone explain to me how I should go about fixing this type signature?

Tags: haskell, types, persistent, yesod

Here's the code, I tried letting type inference figure out the function's type. While the code compiles, it fails at runtime.

```
Ambiguous type variables `b0', `m0' in the constraint:
  (PersistBackend b0 m0) arising from a use of `isFree'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the expression: isFree testDay
In an equation for `it': it = isFree testDay
```

`:t isFree`

`isFree :: PersistBackend b m => C.Day -> b m Bool`

```
>isFree day = do
   match <- selectList [TestStartDate ==. day,
                        TestStatus !=. Passed,
                        TestStatus !=. Failed] []
   if (L.null match) then (liftIO $ return True) else (liftIO $ return False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarrassing. One one hand, this problem did get me to delve into the depths of Yesod monads. One the other hand, this question was already answered for me. When you run a database action, pass the result to runDB like so.

```
>isFree day = do
   match <- runDB $ selectList [TestStartDate ==. day,
                                TestStatus !=. Passed,
                                TestStatus !=. Failed] []
   if (L.null match) then (liftIO $ return True) else (liftIO $ return False)
```

Answer (score 4):

ghci is telling you that it doesn't know which type expressions to choose for `b` and `m`. All you have to do is tell it,

```
isFree testDay :: Foo Bar Bool
```

In real programmes, these type variables are usually determined at the use site, so you rarely have to specify an expression's type there. At the ghci prompt, the context is missing, so you often have to do it.

Unrelated, the last line of isFree would better be `return $ L.null match`

Comment: `liftIO (return x)` is probably just `return x`. Not sure if there are any "laws" for `MonadIO` or `MonadTrans` instances, but if there were, that would surely be one. =)

Comment: Not sure what Foo and Bar need to be.

Comment: D'oh. Of course, thanks. To quote my favourite signature: "If I haven't seen further, it is by standing in the footprints of giants."

Comment: @MichaelLitchard: whatever things you want, as long as there's an `instance PersistBackend Foo Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

"While the code compiles, it fails at runtime." is ***very unlikely*** to be an error in supplying a type to this function.

What does "fail" mean?